# How to print only the output of dbms_out from a sqlplus script launched from powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

myscript.sql:

```
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
set heading off
set echo off


DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
        select 2 from dual
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c1
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.object_text );
    END LOOP;
END;
/
exit;
```

I call my script with that:

```
sqlplus  user/pass@database  @Dpath\myscript.sql  -S | Out-String | echo
```

1. SQL*Plus Version..........is always printed in the beginning. I don't want it.
2. the lines of my query are printed. that is OK.
3. Disconnected .... from Oracle Database  is always printeed in the end.  I don't want it

This code is just a reproductible example.I know that for the particular case, there is other way to do that. But what I want is to print just the dbms_out

Comment: The `-s` (or `-silent`) flag [will suppress the banner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318773/266304), but also the statement being executed; are you sure you want to see that? But that flag has to be *before* the `@script` part (and the credentials), otherwise it's just seen as another positional parameter.

Comment: Ok it's working now. the banner isn't printed. But the output from prompt or dbms_output is printed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `SPOOL` to create a separate file, where you will have full control of what is printed. You can also use a combination of the options `SET FEEDBACK OFF`, `SET HEAD OFF` and `SET VERIFY OFF` to remove the number of rows received, column names etc. so that your file looks more like an actual report instead of redirected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    set serveroutput on
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set echo off

    DECLARE
        CURSOR c1 IS
            select 2 as object_text  from dual;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN c1
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.object_text );
        END LOOP;
    END;
    /
    EXIT;


    PS C:\otr> sqlplus -s user/password@dev19  @c:\otr\file1.sql  -S | Out-String | echo
    2
```